# Domainname to website's subdomain

Tags: php, user-accounts, subdomain, domain-name

I hope this is not a duplicate question, but I can't find a good answer. I'm a newbie when it comes to domainnames, servers, etc...

I have created a website **www.mywebsite.com**. Here, members can create an account. By creating an account, they get their own url: **www.mywebsite.com/username**.

They now have a own "website" where they can access the following links:

- www.mywebsite.com/username/about-me
- www.mywebsite.com/username/contact-me
- www.mywebsite.com/username/blog
- ...

In a lot of cases, these members already have their own domainname (**www.username.com**).
I would like to know how it's possible to link this domainname to their "website" they create on my site.

**Examples**:

- *www.username.com* points to www.mywebsite.com/username
- *www.username.com/about-me* points to www.mywebsite.com/username/about-me
- *www.username.com/contact-me* points to www.mywebsite.com/username/contact-me
- ...

I'm using a PHP hosting and thus is my website written in PHP.
To get started, it should not be automated. I will do it manually with the first cases. How should I get started with this?

Comment: why not do this in javascript? Set a variable that the user is able to change if there is a new domain. Then, in javascript, check to see if the PHP variable is passed and if it is, redirect if the top level domain is not the new one they have saved (that you pass to the javascript via php)

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell:

1. You need to make sure that your site is the *default* site on the server. This probably won't be the case if you are using shared hosting.
2. The DNS for the domain name needs to be pointed at the IP address of your server.
3. In your PHP examine `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`, check that it isn't the hostname for your own site, match it against the user (probably using a database lookup) and then use that instead of the first path segment of the URL to determine which user's data to load.

You'll also need to make sure that you handle `/foo` when the HTTP_HOST matches a user in the same way that you would handle `/$USER/foo` normally.

Comment: Thank you! I'm using a shared hosting service, so this will be a problem?

Comment: @user1141796 — Very probably.